# C# Wpf Foreach InvalidOperationException Multithreading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, canvas

I have a `Canvas` with a lot of little Canvas inside. If I click any of them, it creates a `Thread` with a specific method (add another little canvas to the main canvas and move around it for example). I need to make some of those little canvas grow when I click a specific button. So I tried with a `foreach` loop but the application crashes and shows me this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

I thought that happens because there was a context switching, so I added a lock to the method, but the problem continues. My code is below:

```
private void BacteriaPsiEspecial(object sender , MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{
  lock (sender)//Maybe here is the problem
  {
    //The application crashes here
    foreach (Canvas LittleCanvas in CanvasSimulador.Children)
    {
      if(LittleCanvas.Uid.Equals("SomeId")) 
      {
        //Method to make each one grow growMethod()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know if `foreach` works to do this. I have to use a lot of threads because all the little canvases are continually moving around the main canvas. The question is, what can I do to make some of those canvas be affected by growMethod()?

Comment: If you are foreach-ing over a collection of something, it expects that collection to not change (i.e. you can add or remove from the collection). I'm assuming somewhere inside you `growMethod()` it is changing what will be part of the collection `CanvasSimulador.Children`. If you can't spot the problem yourself, could you edit the question to include the code in `growMethod()`?

Comment: I can include the code but I think it won't help. If I put instead of growMethod a MessageBox. Show ("Hi"); the problem continues. The other methods related to the other threads changes the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have multiple threads changes the collection you're trying to `foreach` over. Simply put, this won't work. Here are a few options I can think of:

- Put around everything that modifies (add/removes) from the collection you're looping over. This however, will partially eliminate the benefit of using multiple threads, and depending how you write you code, could lead to a deadlock where no thread can proceed since they're all waiting for the lock.
- If the `growMethod()` takes a significant amount of time, you could try getting a copy of the list before iterating over it... the LINQ extension methods `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` should work. But you'd probably still hit the exception, so you might end up adding retry logic, etc... yuck.
- You could potentially limit access to your collection by putting a lock around when you access and modify it:

  ```
  private IEnumerable<Canvas> GetLittleChildren() {
    lock(lockObject) {
      return CanvasSimulador.Children.ToArray();
    }
  }

  private IEnumerable<Canvas> AddChild(Canvas littleCanvas) {
    lock(lockObject) {
      CanvasSimulador.Children.Add(littleCanvas);
    }
  }

  private IEnumerable<Canvas> RemoveChild(Canvas littleCanvas) {
    lock(lockObject) {
      CanvasSimulador.Children.Remove(littleCanvas);
    }
  }
  ```

  I'm still not convinced that's a good method, but it might work...

Comment: I solved it usging delegates. But your solution work ass well, thanks.